# Regex match text not proceded by quotation mark (ignore whitespaces)

Tags: c#, regex

I have following text:

```
SELECT 
    U_ArrObjJson(
        s."Description", s."DateStart", sp.*
    ) as "Result" 
FROM "Supplier" s 
OUTER APPLY( 
    SELECT 
        U_ArrObjJson,
        'U_ArrObjJson(',
'                                             <- THE PROBLEM IS HERE
        U_ArrObjJson(
            p."Id", p."Description", p."Price"
        ) as "Products" 
    FROM "Products" p 
    WHERE p."SupplierId" = s."Id" 
) sp
```

What I need to do is find instances of U_ArrObjJson function which are not proceded quotation mark. I end up with following expression:

```
(?<!\')\bU_ArrObjJson\b[\n\r\s]*[\(]+
```

The problem is that the last occurence of `U_ArrObjJson` is proceded by single quotation mark but there are spaces and new lines indicators between quotation mark and instance of name I looking for.

This expression I need to use with dotnet Regex in my method:

```
var matches = new Regex(@"(?<!\')\bU_ArrObjJson\b[\n\r\s]*[\(]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).Matches(template);
```

How can I modify my expression to ignore preceded spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .NET's regex supports non-fixed width Lookbehinds, you can just add `\s*` to the Lookbehind:

```
(?<!\'\s*)\bU_ArrObjJson\s*\(+
```

**[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%27%5cs*%29%5cbU_ArrObjJson%5cs*%5c%28%2b&i=SELECT+%0d%0a++++U_ArrObjJson%28%0d%0a++++++++s.%22Description%22%2c+s.%22DateStart%22%2c+sp.*%0d%0a++++%29+as+%22Result%22+%0d%0aFROM+%22Supplier%22+s+%0d%0aOUTER+APPLY%28+%0d%0a++++SELECT+%0d%0a++++++++U_ArrObjJson%2c%0d%0a++++++++%27U_ArrObjJson%28%27%2c%0d%0a%27%0d%0a++++++++U_ArrObjJson%28%0d%0a++++++++++++p.%22Id%22%2c+p.%22Description%22%2c+p.%22Price%22%0d%0a++++++++%29+as+%22Products%22+%0d%0a++++FROM+%22Products%22+p+%0d%0a++++WHERE+p.%22SupplierId%22+%3d+s.%22Id%22+%0d%0a%29+sp+%0d%0a)**.

**Notes:**

- `[\n\r\s]` can be replaced with just `\s` here because the latter matches any whitespace character (including EOL). So, `\n\r` is redundant here.
- As indicated by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) in the comments, the second `\b` is also redundant because the function name will either be followed by a whitespace or a `(` character. In both cases, a word boundary is implicitly required.
- Unless you actually want to match the function name followed by multiple `(` characters, you probably should also remove the `+` at the end.

Comment: Works like a charm! I tried this example on https://regex101.com/ without success. It seems that there are really big differences between dotnet and standard regex

Comment: @AdamMrozek There is no "standard" regex. The `[\(]` is equal to `\(` and `\b\s*[\(]+` = `\s*\(` here. No need for a word boundary, it is implicit. Move the lookbehind after `\b`, it will make it more efficient, `\b(?<!'\s*)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! Added a note for the word boundary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, but I pointed that Regex101 do not recognize this syntax. This is the case I wrongly named "Standard Regex".

Comment: @AdamMrozek Regex101 is not "standard" in any way. It is only a valid tester for PCRE, JS, Python `re` and Go (RE2) regex libraries, it does not support the rest.